# Docker 1.5 on IPv6 only host

Tags: routes, docker, ipv6

I have problems with routing traffic from Docker (version 1.5.0) container on IPv6 only host. `nc -w 10 2a00:1450:4010:c07::71 80` outputs `nc: connect to 2a00:1450:4010:c07::71 port 80 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress`.

Following [this documentation](http://docs.docker.com/v1.5/articles/networking/#ipv6) `ifconfig eth0; ifconfig docker0; ip -6 route show` shows:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fa:16:3e:74:4a:b9
          inet6 addr: fe80::f816:3eff:fe74:4ab9/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2a02:6b8:0:1a71::2329/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2a02:6b8:0:1a71:f816:3eff:fe74:4ab9/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:78994 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:20269 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:55503363 (55.5 MB)  TX bytes:1945660 (1.9 MB)

docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 56:84:7a:fe:97:99
          inet addr:172.17.42.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5484:7aff:fefe:9799/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: fe80::1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:90 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:28 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:6528 (6.5 KB)  TX bytes:2840 (2.8 KB)

2001:db8:0:2::/64 dev docker0  metric 1024
2a02:6b8:0:1a71::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256
fe80::/64 dev docker0  proto kernel  metric 256
default via 2a02:6b8:0:1a71::1 dev eth0  metric 2048  mtu 1450 advmss 1390
default via fe80::1 dev eth0  metric 2049  mtu 1450 advmss 1390
```

And `ifconfig eth0; ip -6 route show` within container:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:ac:11:00:09
          inet addr:172.17.0.9  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:acff:fe11:9/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2001:db8:0:2:0:242:ac11:9/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:110 (110.0 B)  TX bytes:90 (90.0 B)

2001:db8:0:2::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256
default via fe80::1 dev eth0  metric 1024
```

IPv6 and IPv4 routing is enabled (`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/forwarding` gives `1` and `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding` gives `1`).

Seems like I need add route from `docker0` bridged IPv6 traffic to `eth0`, but have no idea what exactly to do.

Please halp!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not recommended to do any kind of NAT in IPv6 environment, that defeats the purpose of IPv6.

You can accomplish access to the container through IPv6 using pipework.
Pipework allows more flexible network configuration:

```
sudo docker run -t -i --name myimage <image id from `sudo docker images`> /bin/bash

sudo pipework br4 -i eth1 <container id from `sudo docker ps`> 2001:db8:44::1/24@2001:db8:44::ff

sudo ip a a 2001:db8:44::FF/64 dev br4
```

To be able to reach your container from Internet, you will need to assign an IPv6 address from a subnet of your public IPv6.

By assigning IPv6 address to a new interface in the container (eth1), the IPv4 default route is removed and the new IPv6 default route will point to the new IPv6 default gateway via eth1.

---

**Container interfaces before applying pipework:**

```
root@a0b5f4937c42:/# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
494: eth0: <BROADCAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:49 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.73/16 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:acff:fe11:49/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@a0b5f4937c42:/#
```

**Container interfaces After applying pipework: (eth1)**

```
root@9c8372c70ddc:/# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
498: eth0: <BROADCAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:4a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.74/16 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:acff:fe11:4a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
500: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1e:0a:3f:b3:15:43 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 2001:db8:44:0:1c0a:3fff:feb3:1543/64 scope global dynamic 
       valid_lft 2591994sec preferred_lft 604794sec
    inet6 2001:db8:44::1/24 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1c0a:3fff:feb3:1543/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@9c8372c70ddc:/# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
172.17.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
root@9c8372c70ddc:/# route -6
Kernel IPv6 routing table
Destination                    Next Hop                   Flag Met Ref Use If
2001:db8:44::/64               ::                         UAe  256 0     0 eth1
2001:d00::/24                  ::                         U    256 0     0 eth1
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 0     0 eth0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 0     0 eth1
::/0                           2001:db8:44::ff            UG   1024 0     0 eth1
::/0                           fe80::a8bb:ccff:fe00:100   UGDAe 1024 0     0 eth1
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1     3 lo
::1/128                        ::                         Un   0   1     0 lo
2001:db8:44::1/128             ::                         Un   0   1     0 lo
2001:db8:44:0:1c0a:3fff:feb3:1543/128 ::                         Un   0   1     0 lo
fe80::42:acff:fe11:4a/128      ::                         Un   0   1     0 lo
fe80::1c0a:3fff:feb3:1543/128  ::                         Un   0   1     0 lo
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 2     0 eth0
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 6     0 eth1
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1     3 lo
root@9c8372c70ddc:/#
```

**From container to docker host::**

```
root@9c8372c70ddc:/# ping6 2001:db8:44::ff 
PING 2001:db8:44::ff(2001:db8:44::ff) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2001:db8:44::ff: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.134 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:44::ff: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.062 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:44::ff: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.061 ms
^C
--- 2001:db8:44::ff ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.061/0.085/0.134/0.035 ms
root@9c8372c70ddc:/#
```

**From docker host to container:**

```
ping6 2001:db8:44::1
PING 2001:db8:44::1(2001:db8:44::1) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2001:db8:44::1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.092 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:44::1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.072 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:44::1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.074 ms
64 bytes from 2001:db8:44::1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.075 ms
^C
--- 2001:db8:44::1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 2997ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.072/0.078/0.092/0.010 ms
ajn:~/docker/dockergit$
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution with NAT:

```
ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 2001:db8:0:2::/64 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
```

This will enable routing from docker subnetwork to wide world.

Comment: @SanderSteffann yep, changed it to workaround. Do you now how to get things working without it?

Comment: Sorry, no. I don't have any experience with docker yet. With virtual machines you either route an IPv6 prefix to your box and use that to route to the different VMs or you bridge your LAN to the VMs. No idea how docker does thinks though.

Comment: @SanderSteffann I have strong feeling, that without routed IPv6 segment (like in my case `2001:db8`) there is no solution with route tables, so NAT is the only solution (as in IPv4 case for docker).